# Как отфильтровать массив php что бы получить элементы лишь которые имеют данное значение?

Tags: php

Добрый день есть такой массив php

```
array(6) {
  [0]=>
  array(5) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(14) "Дмитрий"
    ["city"]=>
    string(16) "г.Москва1"
    ["show_home"]=>
    bool(true)
  }
  [1]=>
  array(5) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(14) "Дмитрий"
    ["city"]=>
    string(15) "г.Москва"
    ["show_home"]=>
    bool(false)
  }
  [2]=>
  array(5) {
    string(14) "Дмитрий"
    ["city"]=>
    string(15) "г.Москва"
    ["show_home"]=>
    bool(false)
  }
  [3]=>
  array(5) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(14) "Дмитрий"
    ["city"]=>
    string(16) "г.Москва3"
    ["show_home"]=>
    bool(true)
  }
  [4]=>
  array(5) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(14) "Дмитрий"
    ["city"]=>
    string(15) "г.Москва"
    ["show_home"]=>
    bool(true)
  }
  [5]=>
  array(5) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(14) "Дмитрий"
    ["city"]=>
    string(15) "г.Москва"
    ["show_home"]=>
    bool(false)
  }
}
```

Как отфильтровать его что бы в нем были элементы которые имеют ['show_home'] => bool(true)

Comment: откуда берется массив?

Comment: `foreach ($array as $k => $v) {
    if (!$v['show_home'])
        unset($array[$k]);
}` - самое простое решение пройтись по каждому элементу и удалить элемент, который не удовлетворяет условие.

Answer (score 0):

видимо так

```
$result  = array_filter(function($v){ return $v['show_home']; }, $data);
```

но, возможно, фильтровать надо на этапе выборки данных из БД ? или откуда там вы еще это получаете.